# For Eaching into a Class's Members

Tags: .net

Is there a way to enumerate or simply for each into a class's member variables in .net ?
I have a static class, which i want to use for holding the application settings, so while saving the settings I basically want to copy the values of the Static Class to a Instance of a class containg the same set of (non-static) variables .

SO i thought "if only I could foreach or even for() (for that matter..pun unintended) it would be easier

Comment: In which language ? (this is kind of important, for that sort of question... )

Comment: Is there a way to enumerate or simply for each into a class's member variables in .Net ?

Comment: @Vivek: Why repeat your question verbatim in a comment?

Comment: Wait, this a Community Wiki? People deserve reputation for putting time and effort into providing you valuable answers to this question. Lame.

Comment: @Tarydon
Ok..i've messed up..sorry,
the thing was i forgot to mention the question was for .net context, then @Pascal MARTIN asked what language i was referring to, me being the "brilliant" sort, instead of editing the question ,
I rephrased it in the comment section.

Comment: @Jason I dont understand what you're saying, do you mean by making this a community wiki,  no one gets reputation...if so...I honestly did'nt know...

Comment: @Vivek: You can read all about what community wiki is at meta stackoverflow. This question is not really broad enough to become a community wiki post, I think.

Comment: Oh no....sorry folks...i thought quite the opposite.worst of all i cant seem to undo the "community wiki " aspect of the Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your description, [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) would be a good data type to store your application settings:

```
Dictionary<string, string> settings = new Dictionary<string, string>();
settings["key1"] = "value";
settings["key2"] = "value";

Dictionary<string, string> copy = new Dictionary<string, string>(settings);
copy["key1"] = "override value";
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kv in copy) {
  Console.WriteLine("Key {0} has value {1}", kv.Key, kv.Value);
}
```

a more low-level thing would be to use reflection to retrieve the class's members or fields:

```
foreach (MemberInfo mi in Type.GetType(MyClass).GetMembers()) {
  Console.WriteLine("Member {0} has type {1}",
    mi.Name, mi.MemberType().ToString());
}
```

Comment: So..ok..I think i'll go with the Dictionary method, seems a lot easier. Anyway the reflection thing does look handy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection. If obj is the object you want to look at:

```
foreach (FieldInfo fi in obj.GetType ().GetFields ()) 
    Console.WriteLine ("{0} : {1}", fi.Name, fi.GetValue (obj));
```

Likewise PropertyInfo to enumerate through properties.

Comment: This will only enumerate public fields, which may not be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of, by using reflection:

```
 instance.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance);
```

This does have some limitations, though, such as the security requirement for reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for the [Type.GetFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getfields%28VS.71%29.aspx) method.